# Match all elements of a pattern with a vector and in the same order

Tags: r, sequence

I created a function `yes.seq` that takes two arguments, a pattern `pat` and data `dat`. The function looks for the presence of a pattern in the data and in the same sequence

for example

```
dat <- letters[1:10]
dat
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
pat <- c('a',"c","g")
 
yes.seq(pat = pat,dat = dat)
# [1] TRUE
```

because this sequence is in the pattern *and* in the same order

`"a"` "b" `"c"` "d" "e" "f" `"g"` "h" "i" "j"

If, for example, 'dat' is reversed, then we get `FALSE`:

```
yes.seq(pat = pat, dat = rev(dat))
# [1] FALSE
```

Here is my function

```
yes.seq <- function(pat , dat){  
  lv <- rep(F,length(pat))
  k <- 1     
  for(i in 1:length(dat)){        
            if(dat[i] == pat[k]) 
              {
              lv[k] <- TRUE
              k <- k+1 
              }       
    if(k==length(pat)+1) break
  }
  return(  all(lv)   )
}
```

Are there any more efficient solutions, this function is too slow for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could `paste` them and use either `grepl`

```
grepl(paste(pat, collapse=".*"), paste(dat, collapse=""))
#[1] TRUE
```

or `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(paste(dat, collapse=""), paste(pat, collapse=".*"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```r
yes.seq <- function(pat, dat) {
  all(pat %in% dat) && all(diff(na.omit(match(pat, dat))) > 0)
}
yes.seq(pat, dat)
# [1] TRUE
yes.seq(c(pat, "ZZ"), dat)
# [1] FALSE
yes.seq(pat, rev(dat))
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: These solutions fail, however, if any element in pat shows up before the pattern occurs.  `yes.seq(pat = c("a", "b"), dat = c("b", "a", "b")) # returns FALSE`

Comment: Good catch, sry this doesn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R option

```
yes.seq <- function(pat,dat) identical(order(match(pat, dat)), seq_along(pat))
```