# Match all logic rules with a vector and in the same order

Tags: r, sequence, rules

I have a function that takes two vectors

1. a vector of logical rules `pat`
2. a vector of data `dat`.

The function checks if all the rules have been executed and in the right order

```
dat <- 1:100
pat <- c( "dat<4 & dat>2", "dat>6", "dat>99" )

yes.seq.rule <- function(pat , dat){
  lv <- rep(F,length(pat))
  k <- 1
  for(i in 1:length(dat)){
      res <- eval(parse(text = pat[k]))[i]
      if(res) 
      {
        lv[k] <- TRUE
        k <- k+1 
      }
    if(k==length(pat)+1) break
  }
  return(  all(lv)  )
}
```

The function returns true / false

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446800/match-all-elements-of-a-pattern-with-a-vector-and-in-the-same-order) exactly the same question was asked with exactly the same function, the only difference is that in this question the vector `pat` is logical rules

Question:
Is it possible to make this function faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option which would only loop over the expressions instead of the data

```
f1 <- function(pat, dat) {
   tmp_lst <- lapply(pat, function(x) {
            i1 <- eval(parse(text = x))
              if(any(i1)) min(which(i1))
       })
   if(!any(sapply(tmp_lst, is.null))) {
        tmp <- unlist(tmp_lst)
        identical(tmp, sort(tmp))
    } else FALSE
 }
   

f1(pat, dat)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Loop over the `pat`terns in `lapply`, `eval`uate, get the `min`imum index, make a check where there are only `FALSE` cases i.e. if there is any pattern that returns all FALSE, then the result is FALSE,
or else `unlist` and check if it is `identical` with the `sort`ed index

#### Benchmarks

```
pat <- c( "dat<4 & dat>2", "dat>6", "dat>199", "dat>1e7" )
dat <- 1:1000000
system.time(f1(pat, dat))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.036   0.005   0.042
```

Comment: @mr.T Can you please update your post with that rule so that I can test